# How to send html email with variable as "send to" address in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an HTML document as my email using Google Apps Script. I have a variable set up to send an email to whoever submits my form.

```
 var emailVariable = "example@email.com"

 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailVariable,
    subject: "Example Subject",
    htmlBody: email_html
  });
  volSentEmail.setValue("✓");
}
```

I would expect it to send the email but I get the error:

```
Error
Aug 14, 2019, 11:36:18 PM
Invalid email: [L<?>;@2869b373
    at sendEmail(Code:123)
    at newSumbission(Code:305)
```

I've tried changing the send email to an email string instead of a variable and it works fine.

Comment: did you tried sending  an email to your email account?

Comment: Yes, I have. That's what I was trying to say in the bottom line.

Comment: Where does the error occur? And can you provide the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: variable/ string shouldn't matter. You're missing something else.  Make sure `emailVariable` isn't redeclared elsewhere

Comment: consider debugging the value of `emailVariable` before sending email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can receive emails with your code. As you can see below, we only modified it to add a `email_html` variable and comment out `volSentEmail` (because it doesn't seems related to our problem).

```
  var email_html = "In efficitur sem non nisl fringilla finibus.";
  var emailVariable = "example@mail.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailVariable,
    subject: "Fusce scelerisque tempor dui at molestie",
    htmlBody: email_html
  });
  // volSentEmail.setValue("✓");
```

With this information we can rule out any problem with the method `sendEmail` or the code given. Therefore, the problem must lay outside the scope of this question, maybe in the variable `emailVariable`. We recommend debugging that variable to find out possible redeclarations or similar issues. We hope that this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to offer us more information for further help.

Comment: I'm not sure why or what the difference is but when I Logger.log(emailVariable) it outputs the email as "[[email@test.com]]". Not sure if that helps. Also when I send an email in the format `MailApp.sendEmail(emailVariable, "Subject", "Text");` it works.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped. I found out the problem was right in front of me, I set the emailVariable = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValues(); when it should have been .getValue().